# Background image not rendered on downloaded HTML5 canvas PNG

Tags: jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I have 3 input background images that change onclick and fill the canvas area. I upload other images via file input, position it on top of the bg image. When I save the canvas as a PNG, all images --except the background image-- get rendered. I want all images on the canvas to render and save to PNG.

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated :-)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/carolynrue/1fdcbthh/142/)

javascript:

```
// Buttons onclick change background image of canvas
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#canvascolor > input").click(function() {
    var img = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#myCanvas').css("background-image", "url(" + img + ")");
  });
});
// END Buttons onclick background image of canvas

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', {
  backgroundColor: 'transparent'
});

function renderImage(e) {
  var imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
  fabric.Image.fromURL(imgUrl, function(img) {
    // set default props
    img.set({
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      top: 75,
      left: 75,
      transparentCorners: false
    });
    canvas.add(img);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
}

function saveOnPC() {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
  link.download = 'myImage.png';
  link.click();
}

function click(el) {
  // Simulate click on the element.
  var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
  evt.initEvent('click', true, true);
  el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

document.querySelector('#fileSelect').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var fileInput = document.querySelector('#fileElem');
  //click(fileInput); // Simulate the click with a custom event.
  fileInput.click(); // Or, use the native click() of the file input.
}, false);

$('#remove').click(function() {
  var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (!object) {
    alert('Please select the element to remove');
    return '';
  }
  canvas.remove(object);
});
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="800"></canvas>
<section id="canvascolor">
   <input id="bostonblue" class="canvasborder" type="image" src="https://s26.postimg.org/i3ibods55/blue.jpg">
   <input id="bostonblack" class="canvasborder" type="image" src="https://s26.postimg.org/vlp803yzd/black.jpg">
   <input id="bostonamber" class="canvasborder" type="image" src="https://s26.postimg.org/o5pyeao4p/amber.jpg">
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting background image via css, set background image of canvas using [canvas.setBackgroundImage()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setBackgroundImage)

```
$("#canvascolor > input").click(function () {
    var img = $(this).attr('src');
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(img,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
});
```

Comment: Yes, that function is working perfectly in a different version of this, but no matter where I place that code, I'm no longer able to save canvas as an image. My other version of this canvas uses a file upload (user input) to add a bg image and I want to change self-hosted bg images to canvas onclick. Do you know how to make this code work for image inputs (3 of them) instead of a file input? I have code and a fiddle. 
   jsfiddle.net/carolynrue/q7Z9k/1340/

Comment: Hi, the fiddle works-- it does what is asked of it: Choose a static background image, the background image appears on my canvas on image input click, but only with user upload-- I have background images on my server I want the user to choose from. That's my issue

Comment: @crue Check if you are getting cors issue, while doing `canvas.toDataURL()`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm using PostImage to host my images. How do I check for CORS?

Comment: I checked for cors: XHR status: 200
XHR status text: OK

Comment: @crue are you getting error while saving? Check console

Comment: I don't know how to use local images on jsfiddle

Comment: @crue `3 of them` what do you mean by this,I am confused now, and not able to get what errors you are getting.

Comment: I apologize for confusing you. I have two different fiddles-- one will render bg image on save and one won't. I thought if I modify the function that works from file input type file to input type image, then it could work.

Comment: @crue If you don't want to save the background image, remove it while saving and add that again after save.

Comment: I combined them into one fiddle. the file upload method (first button 'background') saves bg, the button group (bottom buttons) onclick doesn't.  http://jsfiddle.net/carolynrue/q7Z9k/1462/